# Drop down on login page that displays the users that already has an account

Tags: javascript, html, css, .net

I am trying to create a drop down on my login page that would allow for me to choose a user that has already registered. so basically if i register for an account, and proceed back to login , i would be able to click my account in the drop down which will then take me to the relevant user interface. (An example woud be, if i create a user as "insurance" and proceed to login , i want "insurance" to be shown in the drop down and once clicked - it should direct me to a specific Insurance Interface)

You help would be highly appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please review the post on  [ask], to help us help you :) A good [mcve] showing what you have done as well is useful. Good luck.

Comment: Having trouble understanding your question. Please add your code here.